# How to read the text box value into session in php joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

What I am trying to achieve here is, when user input the data on the text box below, how can the value of text box be passed into the "amount"?

By the way, it is for Joomla Database..

```
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value=0 value="<?php $session =& JFactory::getSession(); $session->set('amount', ''); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the input - tag in a  - tag (set the action of the form to POST)
2. Add a submit button, which submits the form
3. On the server side, you can obtain the value with `$_POST['amount']` (name of the input tag)
4. Assign this value to the session `$_SESSION['amount'] = $_POST['amount']`. Or you can use the Joomla syntax in your code-example:

> $session =& JFactory::getSession();
>
> ```
> $session->set('amount', $_POST['amount'])
> ```

Comment: By the way, is this correct method you were saying?? 

<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value=0 value="<?php $session =& JFactory::getSession(); $session->set('amount', $_POST['amount']); ?>"/>

Comment: And what should the code be like for server?? should this code, "$amount= $session->get('amount');" on the server page to get the value?

Answer (score 0):

get the POST value as

```
$amount = JRequest::getInt('amount'); //filtered as INT
$amount = JRequest::get('amount');
```

Common

```
JRequest::get('post'); //all var send via post method
JRequest::get(); //all var send via post or get method. If u too lazy
```

For session check below links:
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_access_session_variables_set_by_an_external_script
http://ostraining.com/howtojoomla/how-tos/development/how-to-use-sessions-in-joomla

Comment: By the way, is this correct method you were saying?? <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value=0 value="<?php $session =& JFactory::getSession(); $session->set('amount', $_POST['amount']); ?>"/>

Comment: And what should the code be like for server?? should this code, "$amount= $session->get('amount');" on the server page to get the value?

Comment: <?php $session =& JFactory::getSession(); $session->set('amount', JRequest::get('amount')); ?>

<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" value=0 value="<?php echo $session->get('amount'); ?>"/>